# You do not have permission to view this directory or page for Azure Ionic App

Tags: node.js, cordova, azure, typescript, ionic2

My Ionic2 Node.js app run locally and I pushed it successfully to azure with GitBash.

When browsing it is showing:

> "You do not have permission to view this directory or page."

I did add

web.config, process.json, index.js,

```
"start": "node index.js"
```

in package.json and 'azure mobile service' plugin.

No progress. Can someone please assist? Thanks...

[image: Simple ionic blank project]

Web.Config:

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="iisnode" path="index.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
      </handlers>
      <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="SPA">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

process.json:

```
{
  "name": "worker",
  "script": "./index.js",
  "instances": 1,
  "merge_logs": true,
  "log_date_format": "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z",
  "watch": true,
  "watch_options": {
    "followSymlinks": true,
    "usePolling": true,
    "interval": 5
  }
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "io.cordova.myappd3d469",
  "author": "",
  "homepage": "",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve",
    "watch": "ionic-app-scripts watch"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.2.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "1.1.7",
    "ionic-angular": "2.0.1",
    "ionic-native": "2.4.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
    "zone.js": "0.6.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.1.0",
    "typescript": "2.0.9"
  },
  "description": "Ionic2Blank: An Ionic project",
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [],
  "-vs-binding": {
    "BeforeBuild": [ "ionic:build" ]
  }
}
```

index.js:

```
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {

    response.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/plain" });
    response.end("Hello World!");

});

var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;
server.listen(port);

console.log("Server running at http://localhost:%d", port);
```

Azure web app settings:

[image]

Comment: Can you please include the full content of your `web.config` in the question?

Comment: Ok done, but remember it is thinking the www folder is the root folder for some reason...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following `web.config` instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="iisnode" path="index.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
        </handlers>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <!-- First we consider whether the incoming URL matches a physical file in the /public folder -->
                <rule name="StaticContent">
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}" />
                </rule>
                <!-- All other URLs are mapped to the node.js site entry point -->
                <rule name="DynamicContent">
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.js" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Well, you need to build Ionic2 app locally, then deploy the compiled files to Azure Web App. And you no longer need to use Node.js process to host them because Azure Web Apps run on Microsoft IIS which can serve static files without a `web.config` file.

Comment: My Ionic2 Node.js app run locally in Visual Studio 2017 and I pushed it successfully to azure web app service with GitBash